# AWS Patch Manager - rollback

Tags: amazon-web-services, patch

I am preparing a patching plan for one of my customers. If I am using Patch Manager, should I create AMI/Snapshot before patching in case of failure and do I need to perform rollback? Thank you in advance for clarification :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good practice to have regular snapshots of servers in-case anything goes wrong. You can use lambda or AWS Backup for this.
For Patching, you need to set baseline as per your needs & your OS. This way you reduce the chance of anything going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, we have regular snapshots. But sometimes it's better to have the latest backup before patching :)